# Excel, select an array of an entire column except a single dynamic cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having a hard time finding the answer to this question. Essentially, I am using a function

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B75,B:B,0)),"Not Found","Value found on row "&MATCH(B75,B:B,0))
```

The MATCH function is designed to cross reference the value in the adjacent B column and compare it against all other values in that column. Idealy, I want those cells to say "not found" telling me that it is a unique value in column B. I can't quite seem how to designate the array in the second value for MATCH to include everything but (in the above example) B75. Of course this would depend on the actual row it was on. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first search is better served by `COUNTIF`, for second one you can use 2 `MATCH` functions for ranges above and below current cell:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B75) = 1,
  "Not Found",
  "Value found on row " & IFERROR(
     MATCH(B75, B$1:B74, 0),
     MATCH(B75, B76:B$9999, 0) + ROW()))
```

where 9999 is maximum row number where you want to look...

Comment: This did exactly what I was trying to do. I know very little syntax for excel, I didn't know that B$1 would make that value static. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try using `COUNTIF` to count how many times the B75 value occurs - if there is only 1 (B75 itself) then it is "Not Found", otherwise you could look for the minimum value excluding 75, e.g. with this "array formula"

`=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B75)=1,"Not Found","Value Found on row "&MIN(IF(ROW(B:B)<>ROW(B75),IF(B:B=B75,ROW(B:B)))))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with I have had this issue a number of times, but I do not think you can do this the way you are trying.

What I would do is this:

Lets say that you have column b:

> B
>
> 1
>
> 5
>
> 2
>
> 77
>
> 2

and you want see which ones are unique. I would in column C use the formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)=1,"unique","not unique")
```

this will show you if the item is unique or not, based off of counting the number of times it appears in your column.

Comment: Yes, COUNTIF was definitely what I was looking for. The only thing about your technique is I also wanted it to tell me where the duplicate was.